# Use jQuery the local variable to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form and it has a username, password variables.
But my requirement is to pass the logged in username to a global variable and use it across the site.

Here I want the value of the username from the function `userLogin()` to be stored in the global username.

Below is the code and please help if I am wrong:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

var username = ?;

/*Login forms functionality */
    $("#submit-login").click(function(){

        userLogin();
    });
    function userLogin() {  

        var username = $('#user').val();
        var password = $('#pass').val();

        var data = $("#login-user").serialize();

    }

});
```

Comment: Hello Nancy, Why question mark in username var initiation? You know already that there will be string value, so you can do var username = "";

Comment: I had the question mark so that it can be replaced with the answer. Not passing anything there. Sorry for the confusion @Kejt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `var` in userLogin() function in order to use the globaly declared `username` variable

Answer (score 1):

When you move across pages and if the browser is refreshed, the values of javascript variables will be lost, to retain these values you can make use of

```
window.sessionStorage();
```

you can store/ retrieve the value as follows

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('user',username);
var loggedInUser = window.sessionStorage.getItem('user');
```

But it is not advisable to store password in windows, you must implement/use some session to create a logged on session.

In your current scenerio you can use `username` without `var`, to make it available globally, but this is not the right practice as you should not be cluttering the global namespace.

There is one way of using a single global variable as

```
myGlobalVariables = {
 "user" : <someValue>,
 ... <more variables as required in you r application>
 }
```

This way you will be creating only one global variable.

Comment: I definitely agree with you @Mitesh in my case this is a singe page application once logged in.

Comment: Most of the apps now being built are SPAs, you just navigate using routing, but its always good to follow good practices, In case you app become larger in future.